# onload page on Vue for showing spinner / loader gif?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuejs2, nuxt.js

jquery has 
`$( document ).ready()` and `onload` before loading the components on its webpage, 
if in Vue, how can we do that? when the user clicks our page, then the spinner showing up and after get done loading all contents, the display gonna be none

one more is that good way to mount() the data before rendering it ??

Answer (score 0):

probably you want **mounted()** method

see this doc
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted